# laravel query builder how to sum multiple specific columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

hello I have a candidate total scores table

sample

[image]

I want to add the casual_wear and evening_gown where candidate ID =1

what I got so far

```
DB::table('total_score')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(casual_wear) as total_scores'))
->where('candidate_number', '=' , '1')
->orderBy('total_scores', 'desc')
->get();
```

i don't know how to add to different columns pls help, tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add the casual_wear and evening_gown where candidate ID =1

Then why can't you just perform addition on those two columns like

```
select casual_wear + evening_gown as some_alias
from total_score
where candidate_ID =1;
```

(OR) probably you meant to do a `SUM()` `GROUP BY candidate_ID` like

```
select SUM(casual_wear) as total_scores,
SUM(evening_gown) as total_scores1
from total_score
GROUP BY candidate_ID
order By SUM(casual_wear) desc;
```

Comment: tnx mate, I didnt know it was that simple, :D